# Detect if same url

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm currently working on a project using Python, and I've encountered a slight issue.

Say I have two urls:

1. URL1 = `'www.google.com'`
2. URL2 = `'google.com/'`

Now obviously these two urls are equivalent: they both direct to the same page. However, my simple implementation of a string comparison cannot detect this. Is there any existing method to detect if 2 urls refer to the same webpage?

(First time post, and I didn't find anything similar to this; my apologies if something like this has already been asked.)

Comment: How about doing a HTTP GET and comparing the headers in the result? What about stuff after the '/'?

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure that this will work...

Comment: I could do something like this I'd imagine; but it would yield a much larger runtime I would think. I'm already running this on thousands of urls (all supplied in a .txt file)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's necessarily "obvious" that the two URLs are equivalent. `www.google.com` and `google.com` could well produce two different pages (as it happens, the latter returns an HTTP 301 response to redirect to the former; however, another site might not do that).

Comment: My first thought was that if you only care about the domain + extension, it seems some regex'ing might work, then.

Comment: For all intensive purposes, I think it's necessary to state that they are equivalent in that they both link the user to the same page. Yes, they might not be immediately equivalent, but when it comes to pageload (which is what I am analyzing), they are "equivalent enough." The bigger picture of this project is to detect what pages are requested upon pageload to then produce a dependency graph. So, say example.com calls xyz.com, and www.xyz.com calls abc.com; I want to say that example.com is dependent on xyz.com, which is in turn dependent on abc.com (and generate a tree structure as a result)

Comment: Just tried it. Google gives back different HTML for each request, because they embed some kind of ID in it's JS and some links. Hence `(google.com).text != (www.google.com).text` when just firing two HTTP requests. Same for HTTP headers, obviously.

Comment: As NPE said, it's not obvious that the two URL are equivalent - those are different URLs, and they may point to a different page. The fact that many (most?) URLs like that point to the same page doesn't mean it will be true for all of them, and there's no way to know unless you fetch the page, as BenDundee suggested. I think the important question here is: if they *are* different URLs, why can't you simply treat them as so? Since you want a dependency graph, you might as well generate the graph with the different subdomains, and generate another only with the bare domain name

Comment: @goncalopp I fear even fetching the page of two URLs and saying that the URLs are "equivalent" if the fetched content is the same, doesn't hold. How many distinct URLs don't produce an empty result or a standard apache 404, etc. As already stated by others, the basic truth here is that the two example URLs given by OP, simply are not the same, nor identical, nor equivalent.

Comment: It's odd that this is so difficult...this MUST be a common problem. Have you checked the great and powerful Google for an API?

Comment: @POB: It's "for all intents and purposes"

Answer (score 0):

You could tokenize the URLs in different components and test only the fields that are revelant to you. One useful python module is [tldextract](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract) which will perform the tokenization for you. Then, you could check if the domains + tlds are the same and then move on to the subdomains. You could then decide to remove some subdomains (like 'www') in your comparison.